# My POST body on composer-rest-server is incorrect

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a function called getAllFieldsInInstitute with a model function

```
@returns(Field[])
transaction GetAllFieldsInInstitute{
  o String instituteId
}
```

I have a similar function called getAllEventTypesInInstitute with a model function:

```
@returns(EventType[])
transaction GetAllEventTypesInInstitute{
  o String instituteId
}
```

The script.js has the same logic file for both functions.
Here are the POST body's for both functions:

[image: This is the POST body for the second function]

I have tested it for GetAllEventTypesInInstitute, and it works as expected.

[image: This is the post body of the first function]

It does not match for GetAllFieldsInInstitute, and does not work. What do I need to change?

Edit: Function body is correct on bluemix: [image: function body on composer bluemix]

I have downloaded the .bna file from bluemix and deployed that on localhost.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to help, you probably need to share your model and logic js file.

Comment: can you add model file code that helps us to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post body on the browser is incorrect. If I copy the post body from composer-playground and post to the API, I get the correct response.